# Segregate a dataframe to another one

Tags: python, pandas

I am a bit new to Python. I am finding it difficult to solve this issue.
I have a dataframe as below-

df:

```
Date    Name    Value   Outcome
1-Mar   xyz     20         1
1-Mar   xyz     50         1
1-Mar   xyz     60         0
1-Mar   abc1    30         0
1-Mar   abc1    70         1
1-Mar   abc1    10         1
1-Mar   abc1    11         0
1-Mar   rbc     56         0
2-Mar   xyz     14         1
2-Mar   xyz     50         1
2-Mar   xyz     60         1
2-Mar   abc1    9          0
2-Mar   abc1    70         1
2-Mar   abc1    10         0
2-Mar   abc1    11         0
2-Mar   rbc     30         0
```

We have to group by date and check for a given class of Name- its least value.

Expected Outcome-

df1:

```
Date    xyz abc1    rbc    Y
1-Mar   20   10     56  2/3=0.66
2-Mar   14    9     30  1/3=0.33
```

Each value for Name here is populated with its least value for that given date.

Here the Y value is calculated as below-

```
       xyz  abc1    rbc
1-Mar   1    1       0
2-Mar   1    0       0
```

These binary values are taken from Outcome column of df.

Note that Name column has several values, I have just pasted a few.

Thanks for the help in advance. Really Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
s = df.groupby(['Name','Date'], as_index=False)['Value'].min()
df1 = s.pivot(index='Date', columns='Name')
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)

df1['Y'] = df.merge(s).pivot('Date','Name','Outcome').apply(lambda x: x.sum()/ len(x),1)

print (df1)
```

#### Output:

```
Name    abc1  rbc   xyz     Y
Date                
1-Mar   10     56   20   0.666667
2-Mar   9      30   14   0.333333
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It throws an error at line 1 - 
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Value'.... I tried to rectify it by idxmin or transform function, but it breaks at df1 no column "Date".. The data has to be preserved till the end I suppose.

Comment: Can you run `df.columns.tolist()` and tell me. What you got. Please check your column names.

Comment: s gives me "Value" and "Outcome" as columns with "Date" and "Name" column being the index-
'('abc1', Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00')) and df columns = ['Date', 'Name', 'Value', 'Outcome']

Comment: If possible please update the question with your exact format of your dataframe so I can help.. You may have to do reset_index to reset the index.This code works just fine if you have data similar to what you have posted.

Comment: Thanks Abhi, Actually that did help.I was taking the code wrong.. my bad!!. But I am facing issues on my original dataset.
"ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"
I am trying to use pivot_table and other stack operations. None seems to help!!

Comment: @SparshaDevapalli If possible you can share your csv file [`here`](https://pastebin.com/)  so I can update it. It looks like your index has duplicates entries. Which line throws that error?

Comment: I cannot share the data actually, but the last line in your code throws the error. I tried using drop_duplicates also on df.merge(s).. still doesn't seem to do the work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181854/discussion-between-abhi-and-sparsha-devapalli).